# Bing Azure API search by date range

Tags: search, bing

So I have implemented the Bing Search API (the newest, Azure Marketplace, version).

Basically I am trying to combine Google search results with Bing, I got the Google part done (Google Custom Search API) and now I am stuck with Bing.

My search should support:
- Search by keywords
- Option to exclude keywords
- Option to specify the website you want to search from
- Option to specify date (past 24 hours, past week, past month etc)

I tried many approaches and I searched and searched, but it seems that Bing API does not offer an option to search by date. I however found a way to perform date-specific search using www.bing.com instead of the API.

It is hardly my fault that Bing does not support this, however before I go ahead and explain to my client what he paid for will never be what he wants, I would like to see if any of you have gotten some special hack or any workaround to that problem.

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: I'm afraid you're out of luck http://www.bing.com/community/bingsearch/f/12244/t/671266.aspx That's a feature I'm missing when using Bing pretty often.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is no longer a feature in Bing. I've heard whispers that they're planning on bringing it back in, but nothing has yet come out of that.

I'm sure this isn't the answer you'd like to hear, but that's the answer I have for you.

It used to be around: http://www.webranking.com/blog/bings-narrow-by-date-search-tool
however, as you can tell, it isn't anymore. I've looked for a workaround, too; perhaps I'm not searching hard enough, but I've come up emptyhanded.